# Using ranges of an enum for simple state tracking

Tags: c++, embedded, c++98

I am using a series of enums used for state management on an embedded system.

What I am now implementing is a system to display the state of particular modules in a simplistic way to a user. So I would like to translate these various states to 3 super states, in this case red/yellow/green to indicate error/configuring/running.

The simple way I have implemented it thus far is as follows.

```
enum State
{
  StateAA = 0,
  StateAB,
  StateAC,
  
  StateBA = 100,
  StateBB,
  StateBC,
  
  StateCA = 200,
  StateCB
};

void DisplayState(State st)
{
    if(st < 100)
        displayColor = red;
    else if(st < 200)
        displayColor = yellow;
    else
        displayColor = green;
}
```

This allows changes to the enum to be managed without adjusting the display function, so long as the ranges are not changed.

However this feels a bit hacky, and I am having trouble wording the question in order to find a better answer. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks "hacky" indeed. Instead consider using a state machine where each state in turn uses its own internal state machine. This internal state should be of no concern to the rest of the program but privately encapsulated.

Also avoid assigning values to the enum manually, if you don't then you can use the enum type as array index, which is handy. And if you don't, you can also use the old school trick of a `State_n` member at the end, which then corresponds to the number of states used. (Which is turn can be `static_assert` against arrays etc to ensure program integrity.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a "fall-through" cases in a `switch`:

```
enum State
{
  StateAA,
  StateAB,
  StateAC,
  
  StateBA,
  StateBB,
  StateBC,
  
  StateCA,
  StateCB
};

void DisplayState(State st)
{
  switch( st )
  {
      case StateAA :
      case StateAB :
      case StateAC :
      {
         displayColor = red;
      }
      break ;

      case StateBA :
      case StateBB :
      case StateBC :
      {
         displayColor = yellow;
      }
      break ;
  
      case StateCA :
      case StateCB :
      default :
      {
        displayColor = green;
      }
      break ;
   }
}
```

In that way, the enumerations for each case need not be contiguous or in a specific range.

If you choose not to do that, at least use the `enum` constants in the condition rather than "magic numbers":

```
if(st < StateBA)
    displayColor = red;
else if(st < StateCA)
    displayColor = yellow;
else
    displayColor = green;
```

Or better, define the groups in the enum:

```
enum State
{
  StateAA,
  StateAB,
  StateAC,

  StateB_GroupStart,
  StateBA = StateB_GroupStart,
  StateBB,
  StateBC,

  StateC_GroupStart,
  StateCA = StateC_GroupStart,
  StateCB
};
```

Then:

```
if(st < StateB_GroupStart)
    displayColor = red;
else if(st < StateC_GroupStart)
    displayColor = yellow;
else
    displayColor = green;
```

I cannot really recommend either of these last two options - they are just a little less "hacky" than your original solution.  They still rely on the specific ordering of the `enum` constants which might be easy to mess up in maintenance if you did not know it was critical - it would need at least a comment to stop the unwary maintainer breaking it.  You can mitigate that to some extent by defineing group-ends ad testing the `st` is between teh start and end, but that just illustrates the how hacky the solution get that cumbersome.  I also requires a usually less efficient `if`/`else if`/`else` chain.

By avoiding making "gaps" in the `enum` values so that each successive value is contiguous means that the switch can be easily optimised into a jump-table.  The gaps were unnecessary in any case if you use the `enum` constants in the condition tests.